# Is it correct to say moon starry nights?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-request

I'm trying to say very briefly that the night was starry and there was the moon also.

**Question**

Is it correct to say *moon starry night*? If not, do you see any option?

**Edit**

Maybe *mooned starry nights*?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Normally if it is a moonlit night, the stars are not as bright as they are on a night without a moon, but if you mean to say that the night has both a moon and bright stars, you could say that many ways:

> "The sky was lit by the moon and the stars."
>
> "The night was starry and moonlit."
>
> "It was a starry, moonlit night."

etc.

But "moon starry night" does not sound idiomatic at all to me.

Comment: i know it is absurd but i like the sound of mooned starry night. is that one correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, "moon" as a verb has a couple of meanings that have nothing to do with the actual moon in the sky: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moon - so if you tried to use "mooned" with the intended meaning "with the moon visible" that would not work.

Comment: "It was a moon-starry night" could be poetic and very nice in the right context.

Comment: Poetry isn't what English learners are usually aiming for at first. It can be very confusing to try to comprehend. But yes, I do see what you mean about the moon-starry night. It has a pretty sound.

Comment: Or "moonlit, starry night"? (Most similar to the question's initial form...)

Comment: @Stobor FWIW, I think "it was a starry moonlit night" is slightly more natural than "it was a moonlit starry night," in the same way that "a big red rubber ball" is more natural than "a red big rubber ball." It _might_ just be due to ["starry night"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Starry_Night) being a recognizable allusion, so breaking up the phrase helps eliminate that allusion from the reader's mind.

Comment: Last example is the clear winner here for smooth reading or speaking.

Comment: Further reading on the point of adjective ordering: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2016/09/07/big-bad-wolf-or-bad-big-wolf-the-surprising-way-we-order-our-words/?utm_term=.c003e51cee58

Answer (score 6):

It's fine to say *starry night* - here, *starry* is a adjective applied to the noun *night*.

We can't say <s>*moon night*</s> - we need to turn *moon* into a adjective.  One guess might be <s>*moony*</s>, but if we look that up, it has very different meaning.  The word we're looking for is *moonlit*, which is an adjective we could use here:

**It was a *moonlit* starry night.**

Answer (score 5):

I can see nothing wrong with "It was a starry night and the moon was also shining". Or just "The moon and stars were shining".

We don't say "a moony night", the phrase "a starry night" is something of a fixed idiom.

Comment: Well we could say a moony night if we had a lot of moons.

Comment: @Joshua we could also say it if members of the Unification Church were out in force... :)

Answer (score 1):

Other answerers have already pointed out that

> It was a starry moonlit night.

fulfills your request adequately. However, word choice can also depend on context — is this supposed to sound poetic? archaic? matter-of-fact?

> The night was lit by the moon and stars above.
>
> The only source of light was the moon and stars.
>
> The stars, almost as bright as the full moon, cast a mystical light over the scene below.
>
> Deneb and Aldebaran blazed cheerily as always, but for once there was only a single moon in the sky.
>
> On a night when both the moon and the stars are visible, set up your telescope on the highest point you can find.

In other words, it's hardly necessary to state that the night was lit by the moon and stars; those are *by definition* the things that are out at night. We don't see many sunlit nights! ([At least not at my latitude.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_sun)) So if you're *explicitly* mentioning the moon and stars, there must be a reason for it. Find that reason and work it in. With more creative possibilities, you'll have correspondingly less need to worry about one particular construction sounding stilted.

Also notice that while the moon comes and goes, the stars are *always* "out" — unless it's cloudy. Thus another option:

> The night was moonlit and clear.